# Laravel code design : best practice

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use a webpage where I have 2 pannels.

The first, on the left, with a search button and the listing of the x last elements added. (Ajax will be used to edit the listing based of the search bar input)

The second pannel, on the right, is the result (all the informations) of the selected element. (By default it's the first one)

The first should be updated when an ajax is made. But the second must not change except when an item on the listing is clicked.

I wonder how to proceed...

---

At the moment, I have 2 differents functions in my controller `index()` and `show()`. In the index view I have a `@yield('show')` and in the show view `@extends('index')`.

The problems is that I have to retrieve for each function :
 The listing of all elements and the full datas of a specific element even if it was already loaded before. That's caused by the yield / extends.

And because of this, when in made a new search in the search bar, the second pannel is refreshed and is no longer the one I selected before

```
//Hospital controller
public function index()
{
    $hospitals = Hospital::orderBy('name')->paginate(15);
    $hospital = Hospital::orderBy('name')->first();
    return view('admin.hospitals.show', compact('hospitals' , 'hospital'));
}

public function show($id)
{
    $hospitals = Hospital::orderBy('name')->paginate(15);
    $hospital = Hospital::find($id);
    return view('admin.hospitals.show', compact('hospitals' , 'hospital' ));
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach( $hospitals as $h )
    <li>
        <a href = "/admin/hospitals/{{ $h->id }}"><b>{{ $h->name }}</b></a>
    </li>
@endforeach
{{ $hospitals->links() }}

@yield('hospital-show')
```

show.blade.php

```
@extends('admin.hospitals.index')
@section('hospital-show')
    //Lot of infos here used by $hospital->myInfo
@endsection
```

I think my code design was badly thought out at first but ... I do not know where to go.

Sorry if it seems obvious for you but I'm very new to laravel and I try to get the best practices

### More information

The second panel is also a CRUD manager. So form can be posted through this interface.

I do not expect a technical solution here, just a way to solve this kind of problem in the future.

Maybe I just have to refuse this kind of feature and simply manage thoses differents options on differents pages | URI's | functions | and views...

What do you guys think about it?

Comment: `The first should be updated when an ajax is made. But the second must not change except when an item on the listing is clicked`. The second panel  is this just server side data? Is this a one page application or are page reloads allowed. As you are using `'hospitals' , 'hospital'` for both functions it could override the current data if not handled properly.

Comment: The second panel is also a CRUD manager, so yes it will be reloaded with a bunch of different datas.

Comment: I would suggest to load all data with an ajax call `initialise`. Then with this data you can call other functions with javascript or a javascript framework or something. By for instance calling onClick functionalities. Make calls with ajax to your Laravel functions if required. I don't believe your understanding in Laravel is wrong but I think the issue here is to seperate client and server data where this is required.